# Xamarin.Forms MVVM - Is there a way to Unset a Binding?

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to programmatically unset a binding? Something like:

```
myLabel.UnsetBinding(Label.TextColorProperty);
```

Surely there's gotta be a way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for the `RemoveBinding()` method: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.RemoveBinding/p/Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty/

For your example:

```
myLabel.RemoveBinding(Label.TextColorProperty);
```

Comment: What in the world - why wouldn't googling "xamarin forms remove binding" bring that up? Strange.

Answer (score 4):

A Binding is attached to a BindableProperty, not a class.

You can just set the Property to anything else and the Binding will be gone;

```
myLabel.Text = String.Empty;
```

Note: The above (Keith's) is the correct answer.

Comment: Oh, that's awesome - I'll give that a try.